# libGDX sqlite чтение с БД

Tags: java, sqlite, libgdx

Создал БД **sqlite** с помощью **SQLiteStudio**, как в **libGDX** считывать данные из таблицы?

Если я правильно понимаю, то должно быть сперва подключение к БД, после указание наименования таблицы, с которой хотим считать, а там уже получение данных с помощью запросов
Как это реализовать в **libgdx**?

Comment: Данные должны только читаться? Писать не надо?

Comment: @Flippy только чтение, заполнены заранее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно скачать библиотеки и поставить необходимые библиотеки. Пример находится там же
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=7499